# Camel/Spring giving the error: "The Prefix broker for element 'broker:broker' is not bound" when declaring ActiveMQ broker

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to use the embedded camel activemq broker. When I include the following xml in my Spring file, I get the error (more complete stack trace at bottom):

```
Line 13 in XML document ... is invalid; ... The prefix "broker" for element "broker:broker" is not bound
```

The xml referenced:

```
<broker:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" brokerName="localhost">
   <broker:transportConnectors>
      <broker:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
   </broker:transportConnectors>
</broker:broker>
```

This XML is taken from the Camel in Action book. I (believe that I) have all the required maven dependencies.

More complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/filecopycontext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 73; The prefix "broker" for element "broker:broker" is not bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
at ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Missing from the topmost  tag, was the line: xmlns:broker="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the `broker` XML namespace/xsd...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:broker="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
          http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
```